# OpenCV: How can I draw a dot that follows the mouse without it creating copies of itself? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, drawing, mouse

I want to create a dot that follows my mouse in an OpenCV window. So far I have this:

```py
if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE and (flags & cv2.EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON):

    cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
```

it follows my mouse, but it creates copies of itself where my mouse was. How can I make it only render where my mouse currently is?

Comment: Keep the original image unmodified and draw the circle into a fresh copy of it in each iteration.

Comment: that, or record the "damage" (as rectangles) and "repair" it (copy subregions) before drawing again. can be cheaper than a complete copy, or might not be.

Comment: Thanks for both of your suggestions, I ended up doing what Dan said and it's working fine.